# switching fragment in sliding menu

Tags: android, menu, slider, fragment

I am using dual panes2 source code from andrew ruffolo in his youtube channel. And i added jfeinstein slide menu in it. i change main menu into hello world and added slide menu in it. but when i click item in the list fragment. it switch only into the slide. not in the main activity. how to switch it into main activity. here is the screenshoot.

[slide menu](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngy5vrcqx7w724y/slide.jpg)

[the problem in here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgvjt00tn0rpc36/blue.jpg)

thanks,

Comment: What kind of magic answer are you expecting? What have you coded, why do you think it goes wrong and at what part of the code? What are you even exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: yay i finally can switch it. i just have to read some switching framgment. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to read on some fragment lifecycle first before added it in activity. and after that try to read some fragment switching. this a good to read http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html